# How to add two optionLabels for DropDownListFor in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to add more than one `optionLabel` in `@Html.DropDownListFor` in ASP.NET MVC? Basically, I have the first optionLabel set to "Please Select" and I want the next one to be "Create New...", before showing rest of the list items.

Select -

- Please Select
- Create New...
- List Item1
- List Item2 and so on

Alternatively, I could decide to not use `@Html.DropDownListFor` and render the dropdown with a loop. But if I do that, then will it still post back the selected value to the action?

I guess I could add the "Create New..." option to the collection that it is bound to. But I'm keeping that as the last option for when nothing else works because it will require creating separate IEnumerable wrappers for each collection that needs this (and doesn't seem like a clean way to do it overall)

Comment: Your last paragraph precisely explains the common approach.

Comment: Thanks @br4d, I'm curious why this approach is better than rendering a select via razor in the view itself?

Comment: When doing this you have to project the collection into selectListItems anyways so you may as well go ahead and add the optionLabels and extra selectListItems there. As for why? It is always good practice to keep logic out of the views.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not. The best solution for this would be to create a `List<SelectListItem>` server side that would have your 'Create new...' option.

Something like this:

```
var options = new List<SelectListItem>();
options.Add(new SelectListItem 
                {
                    Text = "Create new...",
                    Value = "-1"
                });

// Code to loop through rest of options and add them to options
```

Then on your client side, you'd probably want a `change` listener that looks out for a value of `-1` being selected, and then show the form for your new object, or whatever you plan to do whenever they select 'Create new...'

Comment: Thanks. With that approach, we're talking about creating a new property in the ViewModel (or creating a VIewModel if it doesn't exist yet) for each such collection. I'm just curious though about why this approach is considered better than using razor to loop through the collection in the View and rendering a select that way?

Comment: @Achilles because there is no alternative for this solution, you want two custom options that don't have an ID related to them. Of course the alternative could be doing it from JavaScript and inserting it dynamically on page load, but...it would be more troublesome in my opinion